# How to get cheked state from checkbox added at runtime

Tags: c#, checkbox, collections, runtime

Hello I'm having problems getting the state of the checkbox which is added at runtime. A event is triggered when the checkbox is checked/unchecked. from the function invoked by the event a foreach loop goes thru the controls on the form. Then I want to set a label when the checkbox is checked.
This is what I got so far

```
foreach (Control myControl in col)
            {
                if (myControl == col[12])
                {
                    if (myControl == CheckState.Checked)
                    {
                    col[13].Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
                    myControl.Text = "Datum";
                    }
                }

            }
```

The col[12] is the checkbox and col[13] is the label. The nested if loop doesn't work.

What should I use to replace the "myControl == Checkstate.Checked"?

Thanks in advance fore your reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first cast the `Control` to a `CheckBox`, and then examine its `IsChecked` (WPF) property, or the `Checked` property if it's a Windows Forms application.

```
if (((CheckBox)myControl).IsChecked == CheckState.Checked)
```

You also need to check to see if the `Control` is a `CheckBox`

```
if (myControl is CheckBox && ((CheckBox)myControl).IsChecked == CheckState.Checked)
```

Comment: Super, Thanks fore your reply.